# Any reason not to start openvpn as root?

Tags: sudo, vpn

I'm running openvpn (client) on a home ubuntu server.

I currently create the connection with the command:

```
sudo openvpn /path/to/config/file
```

If I don't run it as root, I get an error that the TUN interface can't be created.

I found an [old thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540278) on the topic where someone suggested adding your user to netdev, but after doing that I still get the same error.

How urgent is it to solve this problem? Does it really matter if I init the openvpn connection as root or not? Is it a security hazard?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `sudo su` then `openvpn client.ovpn`

Answer (score 8):

By default OpenVPN runs as `root` because needs it to create [TUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) devices.

I dont know if there's any security hazard, but in their wiki, you can find [a guide to start OPENVPN with other unprivileged user](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/UnprivilegedUser).

Comment: It'd be great if someone could show us a working config.